# Compile pdf file from multiple images scanned in by scanimage --batch

Tags: pdf, scanner

Say I'm scanning in images of documents with something like:

```
scanimage --mode Gray --resolution 300 -x 215 -y 280 --format=tiff \
    --batch=document-p%d.tiff --batch-prompt
```

(In the example I've used `.tiff` format, but I'm open to anything that works.)

What's the easiest way to compile the separate image files into a single PDF file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using ImageMagick is probably the easiest way:

```
convert document-p*.tiff output.pdf
```

Comment: Nice! It didn't even occur to me that ImageMagick would support pdf. It'll be hard to get any easier than that.

Comment: In practice I ended up running `convert document-p*.tiff -compress jpeg -quality 70 document.pdf`, to shrink the  file size by an order of magnitude.

Comment: By default on Ubuntu 18.04 this functionality of imagemagick is disabled, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081895/trouble-with-batch-conversion-of-png-to-pdf-using-convert for how to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
scanimage -p --resolution 250 --mode Gray -x 210 -y 297 | pnmtops -imageheight 11.7 -imagewidth 8.3 | ps2pdf - output.pdf
```